# Getting an element by another element in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a requirement that when clicking an element(Button) should change another element property.
I can do by jquery. But i want to ignore the jquery in my angular project.

In Html,

```
<input type=password />
<button ngclick="changeToTxt()">Change type password to text</button>
```

In controller,

```
app.controller('loginPage', function ($scope) {
   $scope.changeToTxt = function () {
     **// need to get the password element and need to change type = text.....**
   }
});
```

Is there a way(or different/best way) by doing in controller? or need to write a directive for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can easily change the type dynamically

here is the working code [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ffKTy/162/)

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <input type={{test}} />
    <input type="button" value="change" ng-click="changeType()"/>
  </div>
</div>


angular.module('app', []).
  controller('MainController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = "text";

     $scope.changeType = function () {
       $scope.test = "password";

    };
}]);
```

Comment: Is this cross - browser compatible ? I think it does not work on IE. Have you tried it on  different browsers?

Comment: yes. i have tested in all platform. it will work in all.

Comment: Works in IE9 and above not the below http://www.universalwebservices.net/web-programming-resources/javascript/change-input-element-type-using-javascript

Comment: Cool, i want to do like this only. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

you can keep two inputs to do this

you can try something like this

```
<input type="password" ng-model="pwd" ng-show="!showText" />
<input type="text" ng-model="pwd" ng-show="showText" />

<button ng-click="showText = !showText ">Change type password to text</button>
```

here is the working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/StpaJdcXN0nam6gjhCLY?p=preview)

Comment: Nice and best way for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the input type dynamically.

Have you considered using two buttons , one of type password and other of type text. And you can use the ng-hide property to hide one of them on button click( it's a hack).

Comment: Good one. But i thought of passing the element and get that element inside controller scope.(as jquery or javascript direct approach).